# twitter-bootstrap dropdown breaking into multiple lines, how to increase it's width instead?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in my page I am using drop downs in header, my problem is that when the content is more than the size of screen the drop down breaks into another line, [image],

but I like to keep it in one line,
[image]

I don't seems to find a way to solve it, I can't assign dropdowns a fixed left since not all of them are the same width and I don't want to center it, just want it to span to the left,

my current css:

```
header div.nav-dropdown-menu {
    position: fixed;
/*      left: 50%; */
    padding-top: 8px;
    color: #d6223b;
    background-color: rgba(240, 240, 240, 1);
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    min-height: 200px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    border: .08em solid #BEBEBE;
}
```

you can try it here http://www.bootply.com/6dcH6D9916

Comment: At a minimum, we require the HTML for this code in order to help you. Or, if you can provide a Bootlpy or JSFiddle example, *and* your code, that would be best.

Comment: Yeah--this looks like it could be interesting, and useful to others. A bootply or fiddle would be fantastic.

Comment: @TimLewis, yeah guys, right! let me prepare a jsfiddle

Comment: @Ted, added bootply http://www.bootply.com/6dcH6D9916

Answer (score 0):

I was able to write a simple code in jQueryto achieve this, but still trying to figure out if there is a css way for it.

```
                        $("header .nav-dropdown-menu").each(function(index,elm){
                            elm = $(elm);
                            elm.css("right","inherit");
                            if((elm.offset().left+elm.width())>(window.outerWidth-15)){
                                elm.css("right","15px");
                            }else{
                                elm.css("right","inherit");
                            }
                        });
```